# Books to independently study physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

Can anyone give me a list of books to study so that I can "master" (whatever the precise definition of that may be) all the branches of physics? I want to start from the most elementary to the most advanced.

Comment: Excuse me, what is your background so far?

Comment: I'm sure you can find some part of your query answered in this post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/12176/46399